# Core Graphics drawing in iPad applications

Tags: objective-c, ipad, core-graphics

I am working with core graphics. I have viewController class and an objective c class to draw the shapes. In my view controller I have some textfields to enter values.According to that textfield I want to draw the shapes in objective C class.For that I want to pass the values from view controller.m file to objective C class.m file. How can I do that?

Here is my code, but it will not pass the values to objective C class. Hope you understand my problem.

```
-(void)doneEditing{
    objectiveCClass *object=[objectiveCClass alloc];
    object.l=ltxt.text;
}
```

This is the code to pass values from view controller.m to objectiveCClass.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    float l1=[l floatValue];
    float x2=l1+150;

    CGContextRef context4= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context4, 3.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context4, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context4, 150, 400);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context4,x2,400);
    CGContextStrokePath(context4);
}
```

This is the code for the `objectiveCClass`. But it doesn't take the l1 value. It takes l1 value as 0. How can I solve my problem?
Can I solve this using any other method??

Comment: You're not calling `init` after alloc on the Objective-C class.

Comment: I am using init. But still its did not pass the values from view controller class to objectiveC class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you've forgot to send setNeedDisplay message after l1 update.

Comment: how can I send setNeedDisplay message? Can you please explain?

Comment: You have some kind of UIView where drawRect is placed. You have to write something like "[viewWithDrawRect setNeedsDisplay];" in the end of doneEditing.